# Grails- How to display the last uploaded image?

Tags: grails

I used to displayed more than one picture, hence I used the `each`. Now I have to display only the last uploaded picture. How should I changed my code?

```
<g:each in ="${statusMessage?.fetchProductPictureUrls() }" var="picture">
   <div class="feed-picture">
     <div class="fl">
       <img class="single" src="${picture }" alt="Product Picture">
     </div>
  </div>
</g:each>
```

Comment: How do you store image in DB or in file system ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by many ways, here are 2:

1 - Filter the desired image in your controller, service or presenter and in your `.gsp` you just need to access your image variable.

2 - Use a tagLib to do this (not tested):

```
class LastImageTagLib {
    static namespace = "last"

    def image = { attr ->
        //filter your image
        def lastImage = attr.images.last()

        out << "<img class='single' src='${lastImage}' alt='Product Picture'>"
    }
}
```

And in your .gsp:

```
<div class="feed-picture">
    <div class="fl">
        <last:image images="${statusMessage?.fetchProductPictureUrls()}" />
    </div>
</div>
```

I think the first option is better.

Comment: @vcarvalho- the fetchProductPictureUrls() return the list of the picture the user load. Can't I writhe this "<img class="single" src="${statusMessage?.fetchProductPictureUrls()[size-1] }" alt="Product Picture">" or something like this?

Comment: If it is an ordered list then yes, you could use `src="${statusMessage?.fetchProductPictureUrls()[size-1] }"` or `src="${statusMessage?.fetchProductPictureUrls().last()}"`

Comment: @vcarvalho-for some reason it works only with ?. before the "last"- any idea why?

Comment: Probably your `fetchProductPictureUrls()` method is returning null instead of an empty list. Take a look [here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Operators#Operators-SafeNavigationOperator(?.))

Comment: is it relevant even in case the list is not empty?

Comment: If your list is empty the `?` operator will not work, you will get one `java.util.NoSuchElementException`. The `?` operator prevents access to null elements (to avoid `NullPointerException`), so if your list is not empty you don't need to use it.

Comment: that's the issue- I got an error if I don't use "?" even if the list is not empty

Answer (score 0):

So going on the code above I am unsure if the list "fetchProductPicturesUrls" is sorted or not.

If it is, you have a few options.

You can grab the last entry of the list by leveraging the .last() method.
http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/List.html

OR

You can grab the list size and track the count by setting the status flag in your foreach loop.
http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/each.html

Suggestion:
I would recommend storing images on disk or in the cloud vs storing them in the database.

A nice way to maintain these images is to create a domain. Here is a sample I use for S3 images.

```
class S3Image {

 Date dateCreated
 Date lastUpdated
 String imageUrl
 String imageName

 static constraints = {
    imageUrl(blank:false)
    imageName(blank:false)  
 }
}
```